# Unable to delete records in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

When I modify and delete data in a DataGridView, I get the error:

```
The record cannot be deleted or changed because table 'Table Name' includes related records.
```

but I can add new data, only cannot modify and delete data.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/132139

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delete the 'child' records first. If you don't do this these records will be 'orphaned', precisely what the error message warning you of. The easiest way of doing this is setting the [cascade delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) property on the relationship between the tables in the database.